# How to control the size of MasterDetailsBlock component in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have editor that is using `MasterDetailsBlock`, where the master and detail part contains a Section each as direct child. Master's section contains a `Table` and a few buttons and Detail's Section contains a couple of `StyledText`. I am using `FormLayout` to control

I am trying to fix the size of the `MasterDetailsBlock` which currently is too big to my liking and unable to do it. I tried calling `setSize()` on all component from the top to bottom. I tried `setMinWidth(`) or `setMinHeight()` on some of the components. I tried adjust the `FormData` and `FormAttachment` parameters. All without success.

I have adjusted the `sashForm.setWeight()`, it does adjust the ratio between master and detail part, but does not help with fixing the whole editor size.

From the behaviour that I see playing with all different values, it seems the master part size is tied to the size of the `Table` which never change even though I tried changing it.

Any idea what should I do to force the size?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set the recommended size, did you call layout on the global form?

See this [thread as an illustration](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg41342.html).